# CannotVerifyCopySource, extended message: The specified blob does not exist. in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

While connecting from a Azure Data Factory  to My Azure Blob storage I am getting the following error.
Error: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found., HTTP status code: 404, HTTP status message The specified blob does not exist., extended status code: CannotVerifyCopySource, extended message: The specified blob does not exist.

Comment: You aren't really giving us much to go on here! You haven't even asked a question. This is currently a statement.... Probably why you've been down voted (not by me). Can you provide some JSON for the linked service and the dataset?...  I'll have a complete guess and say the most common reason for this is because you haven't specified the container within the blob where the file lives. Maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The error information had shown the issue reason `The specified blob does not exist.`, which be listed in [`Blob Service Error Codes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/blob-service-error-codes) as below.

[image]

My guess is that you were copying some blobs which have been also using by other process like HDInsight as your thread tag. When Azure Data Factory was ready for doing the copy operation, the specified blob as a temporary object had been deleted. Please check and make sure whether exists this case.